Not able to see Natural plugin in market place after installing it through Install new software from eclipse
Not able to see Natural plugin in market place after installing it through Install new software from eclipse. I added a Natural plugin from https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural and it got installed, but when i went to market place and typed cucumber its only showing me cucumber and not natural plugin. i have attached an image too.
Any idea what did i do wrong. Please let me know how do i solve this?
enter image description here
